# How to copy Default Value using SSIS?

Tags: ssis

I created Transfer SQL Server Objects Task in the SSIS. It seems to work but Default Value doen't copy properly. Is there any way to copy Default Value using SSIS?

Comment: do you mean a Transfer Database task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A default value is usually a constraint. Do you have the option to transfer constraints enabled?

Just a few lines down from where you define the tables to copy, there are two options

1. CopyAllDefaults
2. DefaultsList

Take your pick, and it should move over.